# Unable to compile pyglpk on OSX 10.8 / Ubuntu 14.x

Tags: python, macos, glpk

I am struggling to compile PyGLPK on OSX 10.8. I have installed glpk and gmp
through homebrew. I have verified that the following files are all present in
/usr/local/include

```
gmp.h
gmpxx.h
glpk.h
```

Yet I still get the following error.

```
python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'glpk' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -Isrc -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/glpk.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/src/glpk.o -m32
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -Isrc -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lp.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/src/lp.o -m32
In file included from src/lp.c:24:
src/kkt.h:30:3: error: unknown type name 'LPXKKT'
  LPXKKT kkt;
  ^
src/lp.c:182:18: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lpx_read_model' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      self->lp = lpx_read_model(model[0], model[1], model[2]);
                 ^
src/lp.c:182:16: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'glp_prob *' (aka 'struct glp_prob *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
      self->lp = lpx_read_model(model[0], model[1], model[2]);
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lp.c:338:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lpx_read_bas' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if (lpx_read_bas(LP, bas_filename)) {
      ^
src/lp.c:349:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_OK'
  case LPX_E_OK:        Py_RETURN_NONE;
       ^
src/lp.c:350:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_FAULT'
  case LPX_E_FAULT:     return PyString_FromString("fault");
       ^
src/lp.c:351:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_OBJLL'
  case LPX_E_OBJLL:     return PyString_FromString("objll");
       ^
src/lp.c:352:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_OBJUL'
  case LPX_E_OBJUL:     return PyString_FromString("objul");
       ^
src/lp.c:353:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_ITLIM'
  case LPX_E_ITLIM:     return PyString_FromString("itlim");
       ^
src/lp.c:354:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_TMLIM'
  case LPX_E_TMLIM:     return PyString_FromString("tmlim");
       ^
src/lp.c:355:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_SING'
  case LPX_E_SING:      return PyString_FromString("sing");
       ^
src/lp.c:357:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_NOPFS'
  case LPX_E_NOPFS:     return PyString_FromString("nopfs");
       ^
src/lp.c:358:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_NODFS'
  case LPX_E_NODFS:     return PyString_FromString("nodfs");
       ^
src/lp.c:360:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_NOFEAS'
  case LPX_E_NOFEAS:    return PyString_FromString("nofeas");
       ^
src/lp.c:361:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_NOCONV'
  case LPX_E_NOCONV:    return PyString_FromString("noconv");
       ^
src/lp.c:362:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_INSTAB'
  case LPX_E_INSTAB:    return PyString_FromString("instab");
       ^
src/lp.c:492:16: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lpx_exact' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  int retval = lpx_exact(LP);
               ^
src/lp.c:493:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_FAULT'
  if (retval!=LPX_E_FAULT) self->last_solver = 0;
              ^
src/lp.c:498:16: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lpx_interior' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  int retval = lpx_interior(LP);
               ^
src/lp.c:499:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_FAULT'
  if (retval!=LPX_E_FAULT) self->last_solver = 1;
              ^
src/lp.c:708:16: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lpx_intopt' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  int retval = lpx_intopt(LP);
               ^
src/lp.c:709:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LPX_E_FAULT'
  if (retval!=LPX_E_FAULT) self->last_solver = 2;
              ^
src/lp.c:730:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lpx_check_kkt' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  lpx_check_kkt(LP, scaling, &(kkt->kkt));
  ^
src/lp.c:737:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'lpx_check_int' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  lpx_check_int(LP, &(kkt->kkt));
  ^
src/lp.c:744:26: error: unknown type name 'LPX'
  static int(*writers[])(LPX*,const char*) = {
                         ^
src/lp.c:745:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'lpx_write_mps'; did you mean 'glp_write_mps'?
    lpx_write_mps, lpx_write_bas, 
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    glp_write_mps
/usr/local/include/glpk.h:723:5: note: 'glp_write_mps' declared here
int glp_write_mps(glp_prob *P, int fmt, const glp_mpscp *parm,
    ^
src/lp.c:745:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'lpx_write_bas'
    lpx_write_mps, lpx_write_bas, 
                   ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
8 warnings and 20 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Could anyone offer a suggestion on how to fix this? I have tried playing with the paths and the enviroment variables but nothing has had any effect.

Comment: I've had the same problem for weeks and haven't found a solution.

Comment: Perhaps pyglpk is now abandonware?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure this is a general fix, but it solved my particular need for GLPK.  I just reverted back to an older version and it worked.

First uninstall the newest:

```
brew remove glpk
```

Then install an old one (4.39).

```
cd $(brew --prefix)
git checkout a82e823 Library/Formula/glpk.rb
brew install glpk
```

Then this worked just fine:

```
pip install glpk
```

Comment: if "git checkout a82e823 ..." doesn't work for you, you can get the file directly from here:
 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/a82e823935e9c4092000bab57d1a6f1cae481dca/Library/Formula/glpk.rb

Answer (score 3):

Would have posted as a comment to the original question, but I have insufficient reputation to do so.

I ran into the same problem when I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 which comes with GLPK 4.52. A lot of the old API has been deprecated and is no longer publicly accessible. I have a work around for this here: https://github.com/bradfordboyle/pyglpk.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, pyglpk doesn't work with newer versions of GLPK.  I think that the last version to work was GLPK 4.47.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error on Ubuntu 14.10 64bit. As per suggestion from @daniel I installed it like so:

Download and install this: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/glpk-4.47.tar.gz

```
$ ./configure
$ make install
```

Download and install latest pymprog: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pymprog/

```
$ python setup.py install
```

All went well.

**EDIT1**: Remember to set the dynamic linker path appropriately

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```