# Error compiling pyglpk for installation (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: python, ubuntu, compiler-errors, installation, glpk

**I believe this may be a general python/gcc problem not specific to pyglpk.**

I'm trying install to pyglpk on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. As I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu both Python 2.7 and 3 are installed.
I believe I've properly installed the listed required dependencies (GLPK and GMP) and I've installed the additional dependencies which another post suggested I might be missing:

```
apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

Here is the error i get when trying to compile pyglpk:

```
sudo make
python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'glpk' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Isrc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/glpk.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/glpk.o -m32
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from src/glpk.c:20:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:7:49: fatal error: i386-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <i386-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h>
                                                 ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

It looks to me like the actual file it's looking for (pyconfig.h) is here:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h
```

while make/gcc seems to be looking for the equivalent file for 32 bit python:

```
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h
```

I'm going to try installing 32 bit Ubuntu instead, even though I should be able to use 32 bit programs on a 64 bit system. I'll report back here.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to vote the post down please leave an explanation of how my post does not show research effort, is not clear, or is not helpful.

I have researched this problem to the best of my ability and have provided what I believe to be a comprehensive and clear description of the problem at hand.

Comment: Consider posting this question at https://askubuntu.com/. I would also suggest you to install 32-bit libraries, e.g., `ia32-libs`, and don't forget to `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Comment: Intriguing. Thanks for your advice! I'm now temped to revert back to 64 bit to give this a try. I've installed and reinstalled Ubuntu far too many times over the past 3 days!

Comment: No, that didn't work. It's looking for a 32 bit version of python itself, which would require me to install 32 bit python along side 64 bit (which seems to be quite a messy process).

Answer (score 2):

I have finally gotten PyGLPK working!

I was able to "solve"**`fatal error: i386-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory`** by installing 32 bit Ubuntu instead of 64 bit.
I would not recommend trying to install the 32 bit version of python on 64 bit Ubuntu as that opens up another huge plethora of issues.
**If you know how to fix this error on 64 bit Ubuntu please speak up!**

---

Once I got past that error I experienced a new error:
**`ImportError: libglpk.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`**
I discovered that *part* of this error is the due to PyGLPK being quite old. The newest version of PyGLPK (v. 0.3) is not compatible with the newest version of GLPK (v 4.58). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22159081/4053066) suggested GLPK v 4.47 was the last working version compatible with PyGLPK, which seems to be working fine.
After installing GLPK v 4.47 the error still appears to occur. I've found that installing python-glpk using the command **`sudo apt-get install python-glpk`** fixes the error. I believe this is because installing python-glpk also installs some dependency which is also necessary for PyGLPK, because even after uninstalling python-glpk PyGLPK continues to work.
I can confirm that following this step while using GLPK v. 4.58 does *not* work. An older version of GLPK *and* whatever dependency python-glpk installs are *both* required.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same error/situation (64 bit linux mint, I'm sorry if its somehow different, total noob here). GLPK 4.55. This version works out the box: 
https://github.com/bradfordboyle/pyglpk
Hope this helps.